# Error C2228: Expression must have class type

Tags: c++

I feel like this should be very easy portion of my project but I don't see how to fix this error. Does the error involve misuse of the pointer on *fout.open?

```
void GetOutput(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename)
{

    *fout.open(filename, std::ios::out);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
(*fout).open(filename, std::ios::out);
```

or this:

```
fout->open(filename, std::ios::out);
```

But, really, both arguments to your function should be references,  the second one should be a const reference.

Comment: I agree. You're de-refferencing the fout, meaning that you're working with the memory location of the class instead with the reference of the class.
So Anon Mail's solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked like a charm.  I was trying everything but that.